# Substituting data using dplyr within a function

Tags: r, function, dplyr

[image]I am am trying to generate charts and for generating appropriate tables I need to use functions. I have written the following code snippet :-

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape)

x<-function(test)
       {
      test0 <- sprintf(test)
      tableResgroup  <-  count(table1,"test0")
      return(test0)
       }

x("R Co")
```

The issue is that the value passes correctly into test0 but dplyr throws an error saying that test0 is not a valid column name, which makes sense.

Since I am kind of new to R can anyone please help? I have a column (with space in its name) and need to subset the dataset on this column. Manually it all works (I use count(table1,`R co`) - R co in single ticks , but I need to write a function since I have many columns with space in their names and I plan to pass these as parameters to my function.

**Data**

```
table1 <- structure(list(Rco = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
    .Label = c("A220", "B334"), class = "factor"), 
    month = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("Feb", "Jan", "Mar"), class = "factor"), 
    Count = c(12, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66)), 
    .Names = c("Rco", "month", "Count"), 
    row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

## the column Rco has a space, so re-name it:
names(table1)[1] <- "R co"
```

[image]

Comment: what are `test` and `table1`? can you add some example data to your question so others can reproduce your issue?

Comment: Hi tospig - table1 is just an input data table that I have read in form a CSV and test is the parameter that I have passed to my function x. test0 is used to store the value of test and in turn I try to filter the the rows on test0(which unfortunately is not working) and store these filtered rows in tableResgroup. table 1 has a column "R Co" (among others) and I wan to filter on individual values of "R Co" and then repeatedly use the function on other columns too.

Comment: So basically what I am trying to accomplish is to pass column name as a function parameter and then use that column's  values to generate counts in tableResgroup. I thought that I could use a function but when I pass the column name as a function , I am unable to get the code to work.

Comment: rather than a screenshot, it would be more helpful if you put the output of `dput(head(table1))`, this way others can directly use your data.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Please see the data below (in the format you need) . This is different from the screenshot but the need is the same,  :-structure(list(Rco = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A220", 
"B334"), class = "factor"), month = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 3L), .Label = c("Feb", "Jan", "Mar"), class = "factor"), 
    Count = c(12, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66)), .Names = c("Rco", "month", 
"Count"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")                               PS - I was unable to separate Rco into R co but the name in the table is actually R co

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following and it worked :-

```
library(dplyr) 
library(reshape) 
x<-function(test) 
  { 
  tableResgroup <- count(table1,table1$`test`) 
  tableResgroup <- reshape::rename(tableResgroup,c("table1$test0"=test)) 
  } 
tableResgroup <- x("R Co")
```

---

Please if someone has an alternate way , do let me know since I am not sure how elegant this is.

Thanks

Comment: Hi , even though this function works okay, today I have a new request to remove null values for R co. Therefore, I followed  the recommended process of first converting the table blanks to na as tableResgroup tableResgroup [tableResgroup == ""] <- NA                                                          tableResgroup  <- tableResgroup[!(is.na(tableResgroup$`test`)), ]         But, I get this warning "Warning message:In is.na(tableMQproblem$test)  is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL' ". Can someone please suggest a method to filter NULL values on my function parameter test.